# Web service call from another ws blocked by firewall

Tags: c#, iis, firewall, iis-express, windows-firewall

My problem is the following:

I got a Web Service running on localhost. When I call it it should connect to another third party web service. But I get a '***Unable to connect to the remote server error***'.

When I call the third party web service from a console application, or from a computer that is not from my organization, I can reach it, but not from a running web service, either IIS or IIS Express. If I use another network I can't reach it too (Smartphone).

I suppose that is a a rule in the firewall for the port or something like that but I tried to open the port in both directions but still can't do nothing.

I use **HttpWebRequest** class to call the other web service.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if disabling the firewall helps

Comment: I can't dissable the firewall, there are an active directory group policy.

Comment: most likely the port is blocked, try if you find an open port in SSL